# Qt set background color for selected QTableWidgetItems

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to choose the background colors of the selected cells in my `QTableWidget`. I use a custom `QTableWidgetItem` that has the following `data` method:

```cpp
QVariant MyItem::data(int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
    {
        if (isSelected())
            return QBrush(Qt::green);
        else
            return QBrush(Qt::blue);
    }
}
```

However, it does not work as expected:

[image: screenshot of my qtablewidget]

I don't really know what to do at this point... Please suggest!

**Note:** For simple cases, I could edit my QSS to add the items' background color, but I want to add a condition to the flow in `data` and using QSS won't be as easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reimplement item delegate too.

```
class ColoredItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ColoredItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

};

void ColoredItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_Selected))
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItem newOption(option);
        newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight,
                                   index.data(Qt::BackgroundRole).value<QBrush>());
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, newOption, index);
        return;
    }

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!